# Visual Studio 2017 C# Formatting: One-Line If Statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, formatting, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 for C#, is there a way to leave one-line if statements on one line without affecting the formatting of other control blocks? The "Place open brace on new line for control blocks" rule under "Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines" will allow if statements to remain on one line, but it will also force all other control blocks to have the curly bracket on the same line.

For example, I'd like the following statement's formatting to be left alone:

```
if(x == null) { return; }
```

Instead of being auto-formatted to this:

```
if(x == null)
{ return; }
```

While also allowing other control statements to keep their curly bracket on the next line like this:

```
foreach(string s in strings)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Not sure about whether VS2017 has changed in this respect, but in VS2015 one could change that behavior of the auto-formatting in the Options dialog under Text Editor --> C# --> Formatting --> Wrapping.

Comment: have you tried not hitting enter at the end of the line?

Comment: @vipersassassin it's an auto format rule

Comment: @elgonzo Ah, the "Leave statements and member declarations on the same line" rule will do it (though it will also leave multiple variable declarations on the same line, which I don't want either, but that's a lot less common than one-line ifs). Thanks!

Comment: you don't need the { } either...    if(x == null) return;

Answer (score 14):

Yes, as suggested by elgonzo's comment that behavior is controlled by going to the "Tools" menu, then Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> Wrapping

Check "Leave statement and member declarations on the same line"

Comment: This was driving me nuts! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Same in VS2022.