# Visual Studio 2017 auto formatting single line if statements without braces

Tags: visual-studio, if-statement, ide, visual-studio-2017, autoformatting

I've always written simple one line if statements in the following style when they are concise and semantically clear (contrived example):

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item == null) continue;

    // ...
}
```

However as of some version of VS2017, it is now insisting that the above should become:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if (item == null)
        continue;

    // ...
}
```

I dislike the latter (yeah, I get that some people will dislike the style I actually *do* want), and every time I copy and paste code it re-formats automatically. I'm getting close to just turning off formatting entirely to prevent this, but does anybody know if there's a toggle to change this without negatively affecting everything else? I've trawled through the options trying everything that sounded related, but no luck. This style has always been supported in VS2013+, and if I remember correctly it even worked when VS2017 first came out.

Changing the "Leave statement and member declarations on the same line" option has no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 C# Formatting: One-Line If Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768743/visual-studio-2017-c-sharp-formatting-one-line-if-statements)

Comment: I tried the two settings in the area as mentioned in the above answer and it does seem that the option/answer noted above is the controlling factor in the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @GreggL Thanks for your reply. I did find that question/answer before, but the option suggested there is checked for me and it's still moving things on to two lines. Possibly some combination of settings at play here?

Answer (score 3):

In `.editorconfig` file , set `"csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = true"`

Answer (score 2):

Turns out after a bit more digging that there was a `.editorconfig` file in the solution. Apparently this silently overrides your global settings in the VS options dialog. I was going to delete the question, but perhaps this will be useful to somebody else in the future.

Comment: Ah, good find. Since .editorconfig files are not generated automatically by VS (as far as I know), how was yours created?

Comment: @GreggL A developer working on MacOS committed it 5 months ago. Long time to be suffering for. Thanks for the help.